# If $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. does $f_n^\pm(x)\to f^{\pm}(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ a sequence that converges a.e. to $f(x)$. For a function $g$ we denote $g^+(x)=\max\{g(x),0\}$ and $g^-(x)=-\min\{g(x),0\}$. Does $f_n^\pm(x)\to f^{\pm}(x)$ ?

I tries ad follow : fix $x$. Let $\mathcal N=\{n\mid f_n(x)\geq 0\}$ and $\mathcal K=\{n\mid f_n(x)<0\}$. If $|\mathcal K|$ is finite, then  there is $N$ s.t. $$0\leq f_n^+(x)=f_n(x)\to f(x)=f^+(x).$$ If $|\mathcal N|$ is finite, we prove that it's true in the same way. But if $\mathcal N$ and $\mathcal K$ are infinite, I'm not sure if this hold. Any idea ?

Comment: Similar to the answer: always remember that $g^+=\frac{g+\lvert g\rvert}{2}$ and $g^-=\frac{\lvert g\rvert-g}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ t \to \max \{t,0\}$ is a continuous function so $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ implies $f_n^{+}(x) \to f^{+} (x)$. Similary for $f_n^{-}$.